# Java SWT extending another class for Dialogs

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, extends

Every dialog window in SWT should extend the `Dialog` class, but I also have my own class `View`, that my dialogs also should extend.

OK, you should just make your `View` to `extends Dialog`, you can say. But the problem is, that my `View` shouldn't do it, because it also is used for classes, that aren't SWT dialogs.

Is there a way to overcome this problem?

Comment: Have you thought of refactoring your classes? Lets say: introducing a `DialogView` that extends `Dialog`

Comment: @reto i had 2 AViewClasses: for SWT dialogs (extends Dialog) and SWT application view (extends nothing). But i decided to join them coz thay have 95% identical code, except constuctors and 1 method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class ViewDialog extends Dialog {
    View view;
}

class DialogView extends View {
    Dialog diag;
}
```

Not everything has to extend. Not everything is another object. Some objects have other objects. A dialog can have a view that it displays or a view can have a dialog that displays it. If anything it doesn't really make sense for a dialog to also "be" the content that it displays.